# Laravel 5.1 working with session to track current online uses

Tags: session, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to get the current online users in Laravel but I am getting this error everywhere

```
"RuntimeException in compiled.php line 2591: Session store not set on request"
```

I was following this example "http://laravel.io/forum/03-03-2014-sentry-3-users-online" I did set every correct as I confirm through out here is the snippet of where the error is coming from:

```
public function session()
{
    if (!$this->hasSession()) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Session store not set on request.');
    }
    return $this->getSession();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the Session class

Session::set and Session::get